# JDBC memory usage vs Hibernate memory usage with web app?

Tags: hibernate, memory, jdbc

I am comparing memory usage of Hibernate vs JDBC for a small web app

Assuming an average computer with 4 GB of RAM...

Does anyone have an estimate or actual data on how much memory an application using JDBC to connect to a database uses?

Similarly, does anyone have an estimate or actual data on how much memory an application using Hibernate with

(i) Level Two cache enabled

(ii)Level Two cache disabled

use?

I did some tests myself but the computer used was very slow and rather old so I don't believe my data is very useful and thus would appreciate any rough results/feedback.

Comment: These are too subjective for us to give you a realistic answer. Realize that Hibernate will use a JDBC driver in order to connect to the RDBMS. Also the cache is highly configurable and it's memory usable will be completely based on the amount of data you want to cache.

Comment: do you know of any sample test other have done? I am assuming Hibernate will be more memory intensive and enabling second level cacheing use up even more memory?

Comment: With any type of cache you trade memory for performance. How much memory you let Hibernate use to cache is completely configurable. Are you running into memory problems with Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible to answer other than to observe that since JDBC is a lower-level API, you *could* use it with less memory consumption. Actual amounts of memory consumed will vary enormously depending on datasets to be loaded, cache configurations, and how the code is written. You could easily write code using either JDBC or Hibernate that uses far more memory than the other.